# "P" icon annoyance

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0, beta-sites, icons

As seen on the [Site Directory](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and on the respective sites, here are:

- The icons for [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com), e.g.:
  [image]
  (from http://sstatic.net/physics/img/apple-touch-icon.png)

  and
- The icons for [Parenting](http://parenting.stackexchange.com), e.g.:
  [image]
  (from http://sstatic.net/parenting/img/apple-touch-icon.png)

I know that Physics had its own custom logo for a short time, and will someday get a replacement. And I know that Parenting is likely to launch later this year, at which point *it* will get its own logo.

But for right now, it's confusing—and that's not even taking into account that (theoretically) [Philosophy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2578/philosophy) could go into beta.

**Could these be made unique in some fashion?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I recommend is to go with a sketchy version of the mexican hat favicon / logo that was in the final design, but modified to use the appropriate blue on white sketchy colors:

[image]

[RIP "chalky". Sniff.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/can-we-please-change-the-design-to-black-on-white/488#488)

Comment: ...and Bouncy. RIP Bouncy. _sniff_

Comment: Have you seen the nerve of Programmers having two icons? Steaming mug of coffee and `/*P*/`? The opulence is off-putting!

Comment: Simply Awesome!

Comment: @random: They should get rid of that coffee cup! Whenever I see it, I think it's a Java site.